# Maybe because the salt content in Yippee is a little less

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, prepositional-objects

1. Maybe because the salt content in Yippee is a little less.
2. Maybe because the salt content is a little less in Yippee.

Which one of these two is grammatically correct? Can you throw some light on this type of pattern usage.

Comment: Hello, RGD. Both constructions are Correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think they both sound fine. I am a native speaker and I feel like both sentences are grammatically correct. The second sentence sort of gives the impression that you are asking a question (like you aren’t sure of the salt content) but in a typical conversation either sentence should be understood without issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is was a great.

Comment: Either sentence can sound like a question depending on inflection.